# How to view simpletest results?

Tags: testing

It looks like it's something obvious but I can't find the web interface to view simpletest results. Where should I view the errors besides the DB?

Comment: your-site/admin/reports/dblog

Comment: I don't think I can see the errors there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the Simpletest interface at `admin/config/development/testing`

Be sure to clear your Drupal cache if you have enabled the Simpletest module and you cannot access `admin/config/development/testing`

Comment: There are only two forms: to start testing and to clear the cache. And two tabs: testing and settings. Am I missing something? The tests are still running in the terminal and some of them failed.

Comment: If you start the tests in the web user interface, they won't run in the terminal. They will run in the web interface using batch API and you will see the results afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you have drush installed you can run test via command line:

```
drush test-run YourClassName
```

The errors will show up after the test is run. Testing from command line is faster than using the UI found at admin/config/development/testing. However you cannot see the succesful steps and the verbose messages.

Between tests make sure yo clean the previous Drupal tables

```
drush test-clean
```

Comment: For me, `drush test-run Something` does not actually show the result messages. It shows the summary of passes/fails but no individual messages. Is there a way to get that to show up?